# Azure Application Gateway session swap bug

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have an Azure Application Gateway sending user (HTTPS) traffic to a single backend web server, which is hosting an ASP .Net Framework 4.8 web application in IIS 10; users sign-into the web application using Windows authentication. The Application Gateway is not using cookie-based affinity (as there is only one web server). ASP .Net is using a SQL Server session state database:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" stateNetworkTimeout="30" timeout="30" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="Data source=***********************;Database=ASPState;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True" />
```

When users sign into the web application, as it is using Windows authentication, they are automatically authenticated using their Windows credentials, so they do not have to enter their user id and password. However, they will sometimes be signed in as the wrong user (someone else who is already signed-in). This only happens when using Application Gateway, and does not happen if the users go direct to the web service URL (bypassing Application Gateway).

When this bug happens, the application logs suggest that ASP .Net is getting the session id for the wrong user, i.e., the session id of the other user who is already signed-in. In Global.asax.cs, Session_OnStart the following gets logged:

- Session.SessionID = sessionId for the wrong user
- HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name = Windows userid for the wrong user
- Session.IsNewSession = True
- HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = True (this is to be expected because Windows authentication is being used, so the user is already authenticated by IIS)

My guess is that Application Gateway is not persisting the user's Windows identity correctly between requests.